# Missing $ inserted. [\begin{array}{|c|cccccccccc|}]

Tags: errors, arrays

This latex code

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{array}{|c|cccccccccc|}
\hline
~ & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
\hline
1  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
2  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
3  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
4  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
5  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
6  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
7  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
8  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
9  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
10 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
\hline
\end{array}
\end{figure}
```

Gives the following errors.

```
Missing $ inserted. [\begin{array}{|c|cccccccccc|}]
Missing $ inserted. [\end{array}]
```

What is wrong? It looks right in the pdf but the errors are annoying.

Comment: `array` requires math mode. Replace `array` with `tabular` and use `table` environment instead of a `figure`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Remarks

To create tables in your document you might want to use the `\begin{table}...\end{table}` environment to create a floating table an the `\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}` environment to typeset the contents of the table.

Also consider using the `booktabs` package for better typeset tables.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\section{Simple solution}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|cccccccccc|}
        \hline
           & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        \hline
        1  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        2  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        3  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        4  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        5  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        6  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        7  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        8  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        9  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        10 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Simple solution}
    \label{tab:simple}
\end{table}

\section{Better typography}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c@{\qquad}cccccccccc}
        \toprule
           & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        \midrule
        1  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        2  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        3  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        4  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        5  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        6  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        7  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        8  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        9  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        10 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        \midrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Better typography}
    \label{tab:typo}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Comment: I think in this case better is subjective. I would prefer removing the outer borders and leaving the intersection, row/column 1-2 to distinguish the column names from the data.

Comment: @percusse I agree with you in the case, that the row title on the far left is too similar to the table content (like in this case, where all are numbers), but I think in the most cases you have a literal description and numbers as content, so they can easily be distinguished.